# Automated UI testing of SilverLight on Mac

Tags: silverlight, automated-tests

I'm looking to do automatic UI testing of SilverLight applications on Mac.

There are a few tools to test SilverLight on windows but I couldn't find any that will run tests on Mac.

Anybody know of such a tool?

Shahar

Answer (score 0):

I was referred to this
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UnitTestingSilverlightWithSelenium.aspx

Not the best solution but it is some a start

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Test Manager is a very useful tool for PC.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385901.aspx 
But I'm not sure if its possible for Mac. So you can just test for browsers run on PC. Firefox is also available on Mac as far as I know. I don't think Safari browser behaves diffrent because silverlight is a plugin and most of your code work on this plugin.